# Navigate from one dynamic feature module to another with Jetpack navigation architecture component

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-jetpack-navigation, android-module, android-navigation-graph

How to navigate from the base module or a dynamic module to a dynamic module using the navigation component?

How to define the destination module inside the navigation graph?

Answer (score 1):

### Android Studio 4.0 introduces the dynamic feature module with navigation graph support.

To use the dynamic feature module inside the navigation graph, you need to use [Android Studio 4.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) or above.

### Step 1:

In your main app/build.gradle, define the feature module dependency

```
    android {
    ...
    dynamicFeatures = [":camera", ":video", ":payment"]
   }
```

### Step 2:

In the feature module build.gradle files, define its module dependencies. Note that one dynamic feature module can depend on another dynamic feature module.

In your  payment/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':app')
}
```

In your camera/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':app')
}
```

In your video/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':app')
implementation project(':camera')
}
```

### Step 3:

You need to enable the `feature.on.feature` flag for the Android studio.

1. Go to Help > Edit Custom VM Options
2. add rundebug.feature.on.feature to the file, save the change, and restart Android Studio.

   [image]
3. Run > Edit configurations and in Run/Debug Configuration you can define various installation configurations for testing.

[image]

### Step 4:

You need to use the `DynamicNavHostFragment` instead of the `NavHostFragment`

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
  android:name="androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.
  fragment.DynamicNavHostFragment"
  app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
  … />
```

### Step 5:

Define your nav graph. Here you can use the attribute `app:moduleName` to define the module dependency.

```
    <navigation>
  <fragment
    app:moduleName="featureA"
    android:name="full.path.to.MyFragment"/>
  <activity
    app:moduleName="featureB"
    android:name="full.path.to.MyActivity"/>
</navigation>
```

The navigation library will do the rest for you.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I wasnt able to find Go to Help > Edit Custom VM Options on android studio 4.2, do we need this step in 4.2?